# A question about the maximal domain of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

So I have got the following equation:

$$h(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{x+1}+1}$$

I need to find the maximal domain of the function.

I have tried doing it algebraically:

As this is a square root, $\frac{1}{x+1}+1$, must be greater than $0$ and there is an asymptote at  $x = -1$.

$\frac{1}{x+1}+1 > 0$

$\frac{1}{x+1} > -1$

$ 1 >-x-1$

$1+x>-1$

$\to x>-2$, provided that $x \not= -1$

But this is incorrect $:($

The answers show a different maximal domain. Moreover, I do not know how they got their answer. I need help. Thanks!!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what follows, I will assume that $h$ is a real-valued function of a real variable.

The expression
$$\frac{1}{x + 1}$$
is undefined when $x = -1$.  Thus, we require that $x > -1$ or $x < -1$.

Since we cannot take the square root of a negative number, we require that the radicand (the term inside the square root) be nonnegative.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x + 1} + 1 & \geq 0\\
\frac{1}{x + 1} & \geq -1
\end{align*}
At this point, you made a mistake.  You have to consider two cases, depending on the sign of $x + 1$.

**Case 1:** $x > -1$.

If $x > -1$, then $x + 1 > 0$, so the inequality is preserved if we multiply both sides of the inequality
$$\frac{1}{x + 1} \geq -1$$
by $x + 1$, which yields
\begin{align*}
1 & \geq -x - 1\\
x + 1 & \geq -1\\
x & \geq -2
\end{align*}
which is automatically satisfied if $x > -1$.

**Case 2:** If $x < -1$, then $x + 1 < 0$, so the direction of the inequality is reversed if we multiply both sides of the inequality
$$\frac{1}{x + 1} \geq -1$$
by $x + 1$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
1 & \leq -x - 1\\
x & \leq -2
\end{align*}

Therefore, the domain of the function is $(-\infty, -2] \cup (1, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that should be noted is that strict inequality is not necessary. The square root of 0 exists,  so maximal domain should include the point x=-2

Comment: Well, you got a point but that also would be wrong anyways, take a look at the graph,  my answer is incorrect